# I can no longer access my question via the same account I asked it through. What can I do?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

For reasons beyond me, I can no longer access the following question:

[I solved their problem. Should I involve them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59512/i-solved-their-problem-should-i-involve-them)

What can I do?

Comment: What do you need to do with respect to that question?

Comment: This is the profile of the user who asked that question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/45599/anon You'll see that's an "unregistered" account- You should be able to merge that account with your own to reconnect the question to your account. There's a question somewhere about how to do it. Edit: Looks like you should be able to do so by simply requesting a merge. You can find instructions [in the help center.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 4):

It was asked with an unregistered account, which means if you lost the cookie that tied your browser to the account it is no longer accessible by any means. You'll have to create a new account that is **fully registered** on that site and then [contact us](/contact) to have the unregistered one merged into it if the system doesn't pick it up automatically.